# Is there a way to open a remote registry in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, administration

Im trying to start a remote Registry (regedit) to for example client C001 - Im searching a way to avoid going into regedit and clicking adding from network etc.
Is there a way like:
`regedit \\C001`or something else that I can type into a script?

Thanks for every help

Edit: I dont want to stay in the command line - it should be a command that opens up the registry like normal but on the remote device

Comment: use `reg query \\remote_comp_name\hklm\..,,`. you need the remote computer running the remote registry service

Comment: You will likely need to turn on the [remote registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520653/4190564) and use `REG ADD`.